# How to get token from JWE Encrypt method of Jose Sdk

Tags: c#, json, jwt, jwe, jose

I am new in C# jose jwt. I have been using `JWE.Encrypt()` method.

```
AnyJson anyJson = new AnyJson();
anyJson.page = 2;
anyJson.filters = new Filters();
anyJson.filters.startDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
anyJson.filters.endDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

string key = "bXF9p18KmVjgyzv3lP6otbne1W8PLo6gEE287SMyjeI=";

var payload = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anyJson);

string token = JWE.Encrypt(payload,
               new[] { new JweRecipient(JweAlgorithm.A256KW, Convert.FromBase64String(key), null) }, 
               JweEncryption.A256GCM);
```

and I am getting response in json like

```
{"ciphertext":"PwUATwt8xgGNSh7V2BjhOtlb0rC_GpFKyKWYdx2Fum6SpY6R9TWnH2BPPbK5qJ8_A0Q9MBkbjJkV4vi_CdKPXI1HXKiFmhxtX34pktiWuP-3ggXEMe1BZV--Lz40xRB9FyDgQ9S_SdDlgC6QMNVBQMCjtiKyhFSwIT5Qwb8AZGlew5cd7AVXhcpXAofMdF1ZV8t8JfpmqJe2ucZW06_aaFe9V3bNn9S5bv9b","protected":"eyJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0","iv":"8MD-0rHQDoIEmRXp","tag":"9DNgPKWMfA2jBBehA5IMxQ","header":{"alg":"A256KW"},"encrypted_key":"GXZKICb9L7EP91DQ2bJod3WNOaVjkSjzBcIsH6gk0vECpUwyTNasEw"}
```

but as per the doc given by client, we need to send this JWE token like

```
{ "request": {"Token": "eyJhbGciOiJBMjU2S1ciLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIn0.Hwv8rJUIcWzZgfAe1g8QaXrcczAx2-lvQX0gighE8OPg6L8-L9YyikY4Xx2oWUr2mbsHnS7nbT1dJ59Nz-CpdUk5JwC--Qml.e1rlkqkDbe3yRusnTiDzMw.ddSHOBVCIpU4-jSCqpGbtAsOuDBJnjnP4xFU97TeBOghlk3quvTd0lvkunDNvKOSqlw0zi2Gtz9Y4lZNPVEyYTkqGprjqMFGulcI_0gKzyu7CaFzJjWBicspIo81ljPdwkodNnfjwnuGjEIj5UUgJHcebEaFNDVqgU4Gtsvn9g7LOHVhmGXLOzlNcRbbgp.SQqu8k5C7QoYP0uXSV6H42zb3Ft9ehSfZGzPrUE6vVw"}}
```

which is looks like JSON. How can I send data like this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure you should sent a JWT token that you create your self?
typically a JSON token is issued by an authorization service. That both you and the receiver of the token trusts.